# Некорректный вывод строк для вводы данных

Tags: c, get, printf

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку.
Задание заключается в следующем. Структура элемента массива аттестационные карты группы: фамилия, имя, отчество; курс, возраст, первый семестр (математика, физика, программирование), второй семестр (математика, физика, черчение). По аттестационных карточках группы определить абсолютную успеваемость каждого студента за год. Абсолютная успеваемость - это процентное отношения количества положительных оценок к общему количеству оценок.
Вот мой код

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
struct name_type {
    char firstname[30];
    char lastname[30];
    char secondname[35];
};
struct firstsemestr_type {
    int math;
    int physics;
    int programming;
};
struct secondsemestr_type {
    int smath;
    int sphysics;
    int drawing;
};
struct assessmentcard_type {
    struct name_type NAME;
    int age;
    int course;
    struct firstsemestr_type FSUBJECTS;
    struct secondsemestr_type SSUBJECTS;
};
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int amount, i, count;
    float average;
    float *AVERAGE;
    printf_s("Введите количество студентов: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &amount);
    assessmentcard_type *mas;
    mas = (assessmentcard_type*)malloc(amount * sizeof(assessmentcard_type));
    AVERAGE = (float*)malloc(amount * sizeof(float));
    if (!mas) {
        printf_s("Ошибка");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        count = 0;
        printf("Курс: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &mas[i].course);
        printf("Имя: ");
        gets_s(mas[i].NAME.firstname);
        printf("Отчество: ");
        gets_s(mas[i].NAME.secondname);
        printf("Фамилия: ");
        gets_s(mas[i].NAME.lastname);
        printf("Возраст: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &mas[i].age);
        printf("\tОценки\n");
        printf("Математика (первый семестр): ");
        scanf_s("%d", &mas[i].FSUBJECTS.math);
        if (mas[i].FSUBJECTS.math >= 60)
            count++;
        printf("Физика (первый семестр): ");
        scanf_s("%d", &mas[i].FSUBJECTS.physics);
        if (mas[i].FSUBJECTS.physics >= 60)
            count++;
        printf("Программирование: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &mas[i].FSUBJECTS.programming);
        if (mas[i].FSUBJECTS.programming >= 60)
            count++;
        printf("Математика (второй семестр): ");
        scanf_s("%d", &mas[i].SSUBJECTS.smath);
        if (mas[i].SSUBJECTS.smath >= 60)
            count++;
        printf("Физика (второй семестр): ");
        scanf_s("%d", &mas[i].SSUBJECTS.sphysics);
        if (mas[i].SSUBJECTS.sphysics >= 60)
            count++;
        printf("Черчение: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &mas[i].SSUBJECTS.drawing);
        if (mas[i].SSUBJECTS.drawing >= 60)
            count++;
        average = (count / 6) * 100;
        AVERAGE[i] = average;
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        printf("%s\n",mas[i].NAME.firstname);
        printf("%s\n",mas[i].NAME.lastname);
        printf("%s\n",mas[i].NAME.secondname);
        printf("%d лет\n",mas[i].age);
        printf("%d курс\n", mas[i].course);
        printf("\tОценки\n");
        printf("Математика (первый семестр) %d баллов\n", mas[i].FSUBJECTS.math);
        printf("Физика (первый семестр) %d баллов\n", mas[i].FSUBJECTS.physics);
        printf("Программирование %d баллов\n", mas[i].FSUBJECTS.programming);
        printf("Математика (второй семестр) %d баллов\n", mas[i].SSUBJECTS.smath);
        printf("Физика (второй семестр) %d баллов\n", mas[i].SSUBJECTS.sphysics);
        printf("Черчение %d баллов\n", mas[i].SSUBJECTS.drawing);
        printf("Абсолютная успеваемость %.1f%%", AVERAGE[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(AVERAGE);
    free(mas);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Почему в цикле ввода данных, сразу запрашиваются данные имени и отчества. То есть в консоле пишется Имя: Отчество: . Мне нужно чтобы я сначала вводила имя, а потом отдельно отчество. Помогите, пожалуйста, буду очень благодарна.

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится, но возможно имеет смысл делать `fflush(stdout);` после каждого сообщения, чтобы убедиться, что оно не застряло в буфере.

Comment: mingw-w64 gcc 7.3 x86 posix sjlj проблема воспроизводится. Но есть еще одна проблема. Это не код на языке Си. В языке Си структуру нельзя использовать так для объявления переменных. Нужно либо честно перед каждым объявлением писать слово `struct`, либо использовать `typedef` для объявления типа на основе структуры. Если же программу откомпилировать как `cpp` файл с помощью g++, то все работает, да (почти. еще заменил scanf_s на scanf, чтобы не искать, где оно у mingw). Если чего сформулировал не точно - поправьте меня пожалуйста.

Comment: Что касается вопроса. Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что после `scanf` при вводе числа в буфере ввода остается "бесхозный" перевод строки (кнопку <<ввод>> нажимали ведь?). Вот он и лезет в имя. Чтобы от него избавиться, можно вставить после ввода курса команду `fflush(stdin);`. Это не очень спортивно, но вроде работает. Или может кто-нибудь посоветует более подходящее решение этой проблемы...